# Guardar y abrir un archivo pdf desde sql en c#

Tags: c#, entity-framework

Vengo con un dilema en el cual realmente no tengo ni la mas mínima idea de como abordar o realizar la codificación como el titulo dice necesito guardar un archivo y abrir un pdf en c# , tengo el sgte método en el cual hago uso de entity framwework para traer el dato de tipo varbinary de mi base de datos en base a una previa búsqueda de la fila a modificar , el método que coloco aquí lo modifique usando **Aspose** que es una complemento descargado a través de nuget, realizando la codificación previa para que al dar click en el boton, me realice el guardado del archivo pdf en mi maquina locamente, como primer pasocodifico mi botón que si tengo seleccionado el radio button pdf me realice el guardado del pdf pero al realizarlo me arroja el siguiente error.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Al parecer no encuentra o no realiza el guardado correctamente.

Adjunto codigo de mi boton de abrir pdf

```
 private void btnMost1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (rdbIma.Checked == true)
            {
                btid = 1;
                daoOdont.Mostrar_Imagen(pboxIma, txtCodHisCliP1, lblIdHisCli, btid);
            }
            else if (rdbPdf.Checked == true)
            {
                btpd = 1;
                daoOdont.Mostrar_PDF( txtCodHisCliP1, lblIdHisCli, btpd);            
            }
        }
```

Adjunto codigo del boton mostrar_pdf

```
      public void Mostrar_PDF(TextBox txtCodHisCliP1, Label lblIdHisCli, int Btid)
        {
            try
            {
                MemoryStream ms = null;
                Document document = null;
                String rutapdf = null;
                HtmlLoadOptions options = new HtmlLoadOptions();
                Buscar_Historial_Clinico_ID(txtCodHisCliP1, lblIdHisCli);
                using (Model.DB_DS_Entities db = new Model.DB_DS_Entities())
                {
                    var oImage = db.TBL_HISTORIA_CLINICA.Find(Convert.ToInt32(lblIdHisCli.Text));
                    if (Btid == 1)
                    {
                        ms = new MemoryStream(oImage.HISCLI_PDF_1);
                        rutapdf = daoBack.Crear_Carpeta_Visor()+ @"\TEST.pdf";
                        MessageBox.Show(rutapdf);
                        using (ms = new MemoryStream(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(File.ReadAllText(rutapdf))))
                        {
                            // Initialize a doument from input MemoryStream                            
                            // Save the MemoryStream to PDF file
 document = new Document(ms, options);
                            document.Save(rutapdf);
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("ERROR: " + ex.Message, "ERROR!", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
            }
        }
```

De antemano agradezco su ayuda.

Comment: Cual, es la diferencia a la preguntas que hiciste anteriormente, de abrir una imagen con el visor de imágenes de windows, pq eso no te sirve aquí, yo creo que es lo mismo

Comment: Entra aquí https://www.google.com/amp/s/www.it-swarm-es.com/es/c%2523/guardar-cualquier-archivo-en-la-base-de-datos-simplemente-convertirlo-una-matriz-de-bytes/968216897/amp/

Comment: Lo que puedes hacer  para visualizar  un archivo PDF es utilizar el WebBrowser control  como  contenedor. Lo unico que  tienes que  hacer es leer  el archivo  pdf desde  la base  de  dato, guardarlo en un  directorio temporal  y luego lo visualizas haciendo algo como:  Uri u = new Uri(tmpFile, UriKind.Absolute); webBrowser1.Url = u; Supongo que estas trabajando con formularios  en c#.  El  WebBrowser Control se encarga  de     visualizar el PDF  como si lo abrieras  en un  navegador pero embebidoo en tu form. y puedes configurarlo a tu gusto. No sé si te ayuda en algo.

Comment: Ahora la diferencia es que el cliente requiere que se cargue un pdf y posteriormente si desea abrirlo se lo permite, orita modifique la pregunta añadiendo el codigo que estoy implementado para tratar de obtener el pdf.

Comment: si quieres guardar el PDF en la base de datos y no en una carpeta puedes hacerlo usando con codificador de base64 que guardara tu pdf como un gran texto.
y luego para ver el pdf lo debes decodificar y mostrar o guardar .

Comment: A ver deja ver si te entiendo, tu tienes un pdf en una base de datos, entonces lo extraes de la base de datos y lo guardas localmente en tu pc y despues lo abres, es eso lo que quieres?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Para guardar un **pdf**(o cualquier fichero en sentido general), debes asegurarte de que la propiedad donde se almacenará dicho fichero sea de tipo **Binary** en **EntityFramework**.

Hecho esto entonces procedemos al código que guardará el fichero en la base de datos, para ello usamos un **openFileDialog** para seleccionar el **pdf** que queremos guardar en la base de datos. Una vez que seleccionamos el **pdf** del **openFileDialog** guardamos la ruta del **pdf** seleccionado y usando esta ruta construimos un objeto de tipo **FileStream** cuyo modo de acceso será lectura, una vez construido este **objeto** **FileStream**, lo usamos como parámetro para construir un **objeto de tipo** **BinaryReader**, y es este **objeto** **BinaryReader** quien nos va a guardar el **pdf** como un **arreglo de bytes**. Creamos un **objeto de tipo** **PdfEntidad**, que es así como se llama dicha entidad en el modelo que uso de ejemplo en **EntityFramework**, y en este **objeto** **PdfEntidad** en su **campo** **pdf** guardamos el **arreglo de bytes** del **pdf** que hemos abierto, posteriormente lo añadimos a la base de datos y guardamos toda la información.

```
if (openFileDialog1.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
{
    string ruta = openFileDialog1.FileName;

    using (var stream = new FileStream(ruta, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read))
    {
        using (var reader = new BinaryReader(stream))
        {
            PdfEntidad pdf = new PdfEntidad();

            pdf.Pdf = reader.ReadBytes((int)stream.Length);
            db.PdfEntidadSet.Add(pdf);
            db.SaveChanges();
        }
    }
}
```

Para usar las **clase** **FileStream** y **BinaryReader** debes poner en los **usings**:

```
using System.IO;
```

Al usar esta notación:

```
using(var x = new ...())
{
}
```

Nos aseguramos de que todo lo que construimos dentro de este bloque será destruido una vez se salga de él.

Ahora bien, para sacar el **pdf** de la base de datos y guardarlo localmente en la PC sería:

```
var pdf = db.PdfEntidadSet.FirstOrDefault().Pdf;

using (var fs = new FileStream(otraRuta, FileMode.Create, FileAccess.Write))
{
    fs.Write(pdf, 0, pdf.Length);
}

Process.Start(ruta);
```

En este ejemplo escogemos el primer registro de la base de datos(tú tendrás otro criterio de selección), e igualmente creamos un **objeto de tipo** **FileStream**, solo que esta vez será abierto en modo de escritura. Una vez creado este objeto, entonces se procederá a crear o escribir localmente el fichero **pdf** usando el **método** **Write**, después de que dicho fichero sea creado localmente se procederá a abrirlo mediante el código:

```
Process.Start(otraRuta);//otraRuta es el lugar donde se guardó dicho fichero en la pc
```

Para usar la **clase Process** debes poner en los **usings**:

```
using System.Diagnostics;
```

Para más información entra aqyui, no es **EntityFramework** pero igual te da ideas: https://www.it-swarm-es.com/es/c%23/guardar-cualquier-archivo-en-la-base-de-datos-simplemente-convertirlo-una-matriz-de-bytes/968216897/

Answer (score 0):

por su guía y ayuda eres un héroe sin capa, tomando todas las recomendaciones dejo el código que finalmente quedaría para poder realizar lo requerido.

Como primer paso el código del metodo Guardar_PDF, en donde hago uso de las recomendaciones, haciendo una aclaración o duda que me quedo, en mi base de datos el campo que contiene el pdf esta declarado como **varbinary(MAX)** , ya que lo que yo comprendo es que el entity se basa en el diseño de mi tabla y solo me facilita por decirlo asi el guardado de manera mas eficaz y sencilla asi menos uso de codigo.

```
public void Guardar_PDF(TextBox txtCodHisCliP1, int btpd, String rutaImagen)
    {
        try
        {
            using (Model.DB_DS_Entities db = new Model.DB_DS_Entities())
            {
                if (btpd == 1)
                {
                    using (var stream = new FileStream(rutaImagen, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read))
                    {
                        using (var reader = new BinaryReader(stream))
                        {
                            Model.TBL_HISTORIA_CLINICA pdf = new Model.TBL_HISTORIA_CLINICA();
                            pdf.HISCLI_PDF_1 = reader.ReadBytes((int)stream.Length);
                            db.TBL_HISTORIA_CLINICA.Where(d => d.HISCLI_COD.Equals(txtCodHisCliP1.Text))
                            .Update(x => new Model.TBL_HISTORIA_CLINICA(){HISCLI_PDF_1 = File.ReadAllBytes(rutaImagen)});
                            db.SaveChanges();
                        }
                    }                        
                }
                else if (btpd == 2)
                {
                    using (var stream = new FileStream(rutaImagen, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read))
                    {
                        using (var reader = new BinaryReader(stream))
                        {
                            Model.TBL_HISTORIA_CLINICA pdf = new Model.TBL_HISTORIA_CLINICA();
                            pdf.HISCLI_PDF_2 = reader.ReadBytes((int)stream.Length);
                            db.TBL_HISTORIA_CLINICA.Where(d => d.HISCLI_COD.Equals(txtCodHisCliP1.Text))
                            .Update(x => new Model.TBL_HISTORIA_CLINICA() { HISCLI_PDF_2 = File.ReadAllBytes(rutaImagen) });
                            db.SaveChanges();
                        }
                    }
                }                  
            }
        }
```

Posterior a esto el método que me realiza el que pueda abrir es **Mostrar_PDF** , tomando en cuenta todas las recomendaciones recibidas y una pequeña diferencia que radica al momento de seleccionar el campo , yo añadí un where que es el que me indicaba o me permitía saber cual tenia que pdf debia abrir.

```
var oPdf = db.TBL_HISTORIA_CLINICA.Where(d =>
d.HISCLI_COD.Equals(txtCodHisCliP1.Text)).FirstOrDefault().HISCLI_PDF_1;
```

Posterior a esto el código final

```
 public void Mostrar_PDF(TextBox txtCodHisCliP1, Label lblIdHisCli, int Btid)
    {
        try
        {              
            String rutapdf = null;                
            Buscar_Historial_Clinico_ID(txtCodHisCliP1, lblIdHisCli);
            using (Model.DB_DS_Entities db = new Model.DB_DS_Entities())
            {                    
                if (Btid == 1)
                {                        
                var oPdf = db.TBL_HISTORIA_CLINICA.Where(d => d.HISCLI_COD.Equals(txtCodHisCliP1.Text)).FirstOrDefault().HISCLI_PDF_1;
                    rutapdf = daoBack.Crear_Carpeta_Visor()+ @"\TEST.pdf";
                    MessageBox.Show(rutapdf);
                    using (var fs = new FileStream(rutapdf, FileMode.Create, FileAccess.Write))
                    {
                        fs.Write(oPdf, 0,oPdf.Length);
                    }

                    Process.Start(rutapdf);
                }
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("ERROR: " + ex.Message, "ERROR!", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
        }
    }
```